# How to deploy laravel app with nodejs (socket.io) on heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, deployment, laravel-5

I want to deploy laravel 5.1 app WITH nodejs (socket.io) for realtime to heroku. I can deploy app write by only laravel or only node success, but can't deploy success if I using both of them in once app.
What I have to do to deploy?

```
App_folder
--app
--bootstrap
--config
--node_modules
----express
----socket.io
--database
--....
--Procfile
--server_node.js
```

Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
web: node server_node.js
```

--server_node.js

```
var app =require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    console.log('Had new connection connected');
    socket.on('chat-channelt',function (data){
        io.emit('testchannel',data);
    });
});
server.listen(80);
```